# Databricks use sql jdbc parameters from secrets results in ParseError

Tags: pyspark, databricks, amazon-rds

I have some databricks secrets for connecting to external databases. However, I am looking to use the secrets in sql cells, or in `spark.sql()` functions, and it results in `ParseError`

I am trying to use my databricks secrets to store a AWS RDS credentials (host/port/database/user/password)

If I pull them as secrets and use them on pyspark like this, it works:

```
HOST=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='host')
PORT=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='port')
DATABASE=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='database')
USER=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='username')
PASSWORD=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='password')

jdbc_url="jdbc:postgresql://{}/{}".format(HOST,DATABASE)
conn_properties={'user':USER,'password':PASSWORD}

df=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("query", 'SELECT * FROM some_table') \
    .option("user", USER) \
    .option("password", PASSWORD)\
    .load()
```

Now, on a sql cell I want to reference those parameters as secrets as well. For example, I have this sql statement on a sql cell to connect to a table on RDS

```
%sql 
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW test
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url '<hardcoded_jdb_url_with_visible_values>',
  dbtable 'some_schema.some_table',
  user '<hardcoded_user_visible_values>',
  password '<hardcoded_visible_password_plain_text>'
)
```

How can I avoid hardcoding them on a sql statement and still reference them as the secrets I pulled above like `HOST` `PORT` `DATABASE` `USER` `PASSWORD`

I tried this on python cell, however, it fails:

```
HOST=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='host')
PORT=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='port')
DATABASE=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='database')
USER=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='username')
PASSWORD=dbutils.secrets.get(scope='sample',key='password')

jdbc_url="jdbc:postgresql://{}/{}".format(HOST,DATABASE)

spark.sql(f'''
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW test
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url {jdbc_url},
  dbtable 'some_schema.some_table
  user {USER},
  password {PASSWORD}
)
'''
)
```

The error that I get is just `ParseError`, with no more message on it

if I `print(jdbc_url)`, naturally, because it's a secret, this is literally what shows in console `jdbc:postgresql://[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes around your variables, should be:

```
spark.sql(f'''
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW test
USING JDBC
OPTIONS (
  url '{jdbc_url}',
  dbtable 'some_schema.some_table',
  user '{USER}',
  password '{PASSWORD}'
)
''')
```